# issue with text above image in php using css

Tags: php, html, css

[image]

I'm using php to scan directory for all jpg and png files and place them below the text,but for the last image text is not placed properly. what im doing wrong here?

php code:

```
 <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<?php
$dir = "images/";
function s($num){
    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
        echo "&nbsp;";
}
// Open a directory, and read its contents
echo "<div class=\"container\">";
if (is_dir($dir)){
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
    {
      $File_name =  realpath('$file');
      $full_path = $dir.$file;
      $ext = pathinfo($file);

      if($ext['extension']=="jpg" || $ext['extension']=="png")
        {
          echo "<span class=\"scan-text\">Some text above</span>";
          echo "<img src=\"{$full_path}\" height=\"100\" width=\"100\">";

        }   
    }
    closedir($dh);
  }
  echo "</div>";    
}
?>
```

CSS Code:

```
.scan-text {
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    width:100px;
}
img {
    margin-top:70px;
    margin-right:10px;
    width=100;
    height=100;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
.container {
    width:1100px;
}
```

Comment: Is it live anywhere?

Comment: no, its on local server only .

Comment: Probably a CSS problem, can you post exact html output somewhere. Its the only was I can diagnose it.

Comment: i have uploaded all the files in here , http://nibble.ooo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, i think there is no need for `position: absolute`, you can add each `textbox and image` in one span and use css to style it

**CSS**

```
.block {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.scan-text {
    display: block;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: 15px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    width:100px;
}
img {         
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
.container {
    width:1100px;
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$dir = 'images/';

function s($num) {
 for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++)
  echo "&nbsp;";
}

// Open a directory, and read its contents
echo "<div class=\"container\">";
if (is_dir($dir)) {
 if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
  while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
   $File_name = realpath('$file');
   $full_path = $dir . $file;
   $ext = pathinfo($file);

   if ($ext['extension'] == "jpg" || $ext['extension'] == "png") {
    echo "<span class=\"block\"><span class=\"scan-text\">Some text above</span>";
    echo "<img src=\"{$full_path}\" height=\"100\" width=\"100\"></span>";
   }
  }
  closedir($dh);
 }
 echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your images have a margin on the right side, that's what's causing this bug.
Remove `margin-right:10px` from `img` and all will be good.

```
img {
    margin-top:70px;
    width:100;
    height:100;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```